# Declaring a type without providing the name

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I've tested some code on gcc in debug mode, but not sure it will work correct for other compilers.
My question is how will any compiler optimize the following c++ code (make_auto macro):

```
class A
{
private:
 void *ptr;
public:
  A(void* _ptr) {ptr = _ptr;}
  ~A() {free(ptr);}
};

#define make_auto(ptr) A(ptr)

int main ()
{
   char *a = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)),*b = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
   make_auto(a);
   make_auto(b);
   return 0;
}
```

Will it always call constructor and destructor of A? Or will compiler optimize this code in any case and delete A(ptr) calls, because it can think that it will not be used more.

**UPD:**

I know about boost and std::auto_ptr. I have own memory manager that is controlling fragmentation of memory and helps to avoid memory leaks. Now I want to "teach" my memory manager to create auto_ptrs like it is doing in boost and stl.

**UPD2:**

Here is complete code, that i'm using and that i thought is working correct:

```
    class AutoPtr
    {
    private:
        void *ptr;
        Application *app;
    public:
        AutoPtr(Application *_app,void *a)
        {
            printf("constructor called\n");
            ptr = a;
            app = _app;
        }
        ~AutoPtr()
        {
            fast_free(app,ptr);
            printf("destructor called\n");
        }

    };
#define make_auto_ptr(app,ptr)  AutoPtr(app,ptr)
    static void AutoPtrTest1()
    {
        test_declare_app

        char *a = fast_alloc(app,char,20);
        char *b = fast_alloc(app,char,11);

        {
            make_auto_ptr(app,a);
            make_auto_ptr(app,b);
        }


        test_free_app
        printf("Autoptrtest1 passed\n");                
    }
```

Output:

constructor called
destructor called
constructor called
destructor called
Autoptrtest1 passed

So it doesn't work correct as i thought (i didn't check destructor calls). But it calls constructors twice as i said before . 
How to change make_auto_ptr for auto-declaring auto-ptrs?

Comment: Am I the only one that doesn't see why Oleg can't use `std/boost::unique_ptr/shared_ptr` with his own `new` and his own `delete`, and let the language take care of the rest?

Comment: Don't think that i'm a "bike inventer". I've already answered why i can't do that. I want to use, but i can't.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing happens, because your code is ill-formed. `A(a);` and `A(b);` declare `a` and `b`. Since `a` has already been declared, and `A` in any case has no default constructor, the compiler shall emit a diagnostic.

If you fix these issues, then the compiler is allowed to optimize away these, if the `malloc` and `free` you are using are the Standard libraries' functions, because that code really has no observable side effects.

An optimizing compiler should know about the special meaning of `malloc` and `free`, and I wouldn't be surprised to see it optimize this away. But for whatever reasons there might be, I can also imagine the compiler doesn't optimize it away. It really depends on your compiler and the flags it uses, but the Standard definitely allows it to optimize here.

Here is the code that `clang -O2 -emit-llvm -S main1.cpp -o -` outputs:

```
define i32 @main() nounwind {
  ret i32 0
}
```

Comment: It should not declare a and b. It should create instance of A twice(should just call A() twice). And destroy them after leaving main.

Comment: @Oli I think you missed something. How is `A(a);` not equivalent to `A a;`?

Comment: +1. "ComeauTest.c", line 17: error: "a" has already been declared in the current scope make_auto(a); ^ "ComeauTest.c", line 17: error: no default constructor exists for class "A" make_auto(a); ^ "ComeauTest.c", line 18: error: "b" has already been declared in the current scope make_auto(b); ^ "ComeauTest.c", line 18: error: no default constructor exists for class "A" make_auto(b); ^

Comment: @Johannes: Indeed I must have missed something!  My compiler agrees with you; this is indeed a declaration (so +1).  Although I'm struggling to understand why...

Comment: @Oli it's not really different from `int(*p)();`. If you remove the star and the function parens, you too end up with `int(p);` being equivalent to `int p;`. Most vexing parse.

Comment: @Johannes: Yes, I suppose so.  I didn't realise that parentheses were valid in declarations, other than for function pointers.

Comment: I didn't know that int(p) is equivalent to int p. But i don't understand why my code is not giving declaration error than?

Comment: @Oleg because your code does `AutoPtr(app, ptr)`. There is no such name as "app, ptr", so a paren around those words will not make it a declaration. FWIW, that temporary doesn't live until the end of its block. It's been destroyed already when the next statement is executed.

Comment: @Johannes. Hold on is `A(a)` not just declaring a temporary object of type 'A' passing 'a' as the parameter!!

Answer (score 4):

Your assumption is correct.  The <s>compiler</s> implementation (correction pointed out by @Steve below) is free to optimise this code away to nothing (assuming it compiles at all), because it has no observable side-effects.

Comment: Not my downvote, but to be precise the *implementation* is free to do nothing. Whether the *compiler* treats memory allocation/free as a no-op is implementation-dependent, and most compilers don't AFAIK, if only because they want to support things like linking against different memory allocators, that themselves might have observable behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the compiler will optimize it out. However, even if it doesn't, the added safety of an auto pointer will likely outweigh a few nanoseconds here or there.  To be more C++-like you should even convert the macro declaration into an inline function that accomplishes the same thing. The compiler is able to optimize out inline functions like macros.  For computational efficiency, concentrate on the data structures and algorithms you use. After you have the best data structures and algorithms, look at low level optimizations like this.

**Edit**

I looked at the code again. I'm having trouble thinking of a situation where the destructor would be optimized out.  Best to assume it wouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

It can't optimise the delete away, that would change the semantics. (Although it could optimise the entire function to nothing.)

But there are better ways of doing this - RAII, scoped_ptr, shared_ptr, unique_ptr etc. And  don't use macros unless you have to.

Comment: There are no semantics, because this code has no side-effects.

Comment: It will always call ~A() if A() was called. The question is: Will it always call A()?

Comment: If that's the question, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned,
`std::auto_ptr` doesn't take user provided deleter as an argument.
However,
`std::unique_ptr` and `std/boost::shared_ptr` can take a deleter.
So, how about overloading `operator new`/`delete` and preparing your own
deleter, and giving the deleter to the above smart pointers?
If those smart pointers aren't allowed, I'd suggest making your `AutoPtr`
take an user provided deleter like the following:

```
void* operator new( size_t s, Application* app ) {
  return malloc( s );
}

void operator delete( void* p, Application* app ) throw() {
  free( p );
}

template< class T >
void delete_( T const* p, Application* app ) {
  p->~T();
  operator delete( (void*) p, app );
}

template< class T >
struct Deleter {
  Application *app;
  Deleter( Application* app ) : app( app ) {}
  void operator()( T const* p ) const { delete_( p, app ); }
};

template< class T, class D = Deleter<T> >
struct AutoPtr {
  T *ptr;
  D del;

  AutoPtr( T* ptr, D const& del ) : ptr( ptr ), del( del ) {}
  ~AutoPtr() { del( ptr ); }
};

int main() {
  Application *app = ...;
  AutoPtr<int> p( new( app ) int, Deleter<int>( app ) );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not really a (direct) answer to your question, but take a look at [boost::scoped_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) as it already achieves what you are trying to do here.

e.g.

```
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::scoped_ptr<char> a(new char);
    boost::scoped_ptr<char> b(new char);
}
```

Comment: I know about boost and std::auto_ptr. I have own memory manager that is controlling fragmentation of memory and helps to avoid memory leaks. Now i want to "teach" my memory manager to create auto_ptrs like it is doing in boost and stl.

Comment: First time I've seen an answer start with "not really an answer to your question".

Comment: @Oleg: If you have implemented your own memory manager can't you just define your own global `operator new` and `operator delete` then continue to use the existing boost and stl?

Comment: @the_drow: I couldn't offer example code in a comment.
@André: sometimes offering a working alternative is better than trying to directly solve the OPs question. :)

Comment: @GrahamS: Unfortunately, no i can't. My alloc and free always have additional parameter (Application*) and i can't remove it, because i need to have several memory managers at one time.

Comment: @Oleg: surely you can wrap those suckers in a nice `new` and `delete`? Heck, you can use other names for them if you want, and use the "right" one in the calling code, and still use regular smart pointers?

Comment: @GrahamS Of course you can: `#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::scoped_ptr<char> a(new char);
    boost::scoped_ptr<char> b(new char);
}`

Comment: @the_drow: Mmm yes, that's much more readable :) My apologies for upsetting you with my apparent breach of comment-vs-answer etiquette. I had mistakenly thought that an alternative *solution* that (I believed) solved the OPs overall problem was a helpful and valid answer. Be sure to berate and downvote @Alan Stokes and @Ise Wisteria whose answers make similar points.